# HOC/Render-Call Back or Library function?

Tags: reactjs, function-composition, higher-order-components

I'm working on a project where a prospect needs to be sent an email about a property they are interested in. There is a top level component that fetches the property information and prospect's contact info from the database and passes to its children. There are two components that share the same process of formatting the information, and then call an email function that sends off an email. A sample of one component looks like this:

```
import sendEmail from 'actions/sendEmail'

class PropertyDetail extends React.Componet {
  state = {
    unit: undefined,
    prospect: undefined,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({
      unit: this.props.unit,
      prospect: this.props.prospect,
    });
  };

  sendEmail = ({ id, address, prospect }) => {
    // quite a bit more gets formatted and packaged up into this payload
    const payload = {
      id,
      address,
      prospectEmail: prospect.email,
    };

    emailFunction(payload);
  };

  handleEmail = () => {
    sendEmail(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.unit.address}</h1>
        <p>Send prospect an email about this property</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleEmail}>Send Email</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the other component looks like this

```
class UpdateShowing extends React.Component {
  state = {
    unit: undefined,
    prospect: undefined,
    showingTime: undefined,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({
      unit: this.props.unit,
      propsect: this.props.prospect,
      showingTime: this.props.showingTime,
    });
  };

  sendEmail = ({ id, address, prospectEmail }) => {
    // quite a bit more gets formatted and packaged up into this payload
    const payload = {
      id,
      address,
      prospectEmail,
    };

    emailFunction(payload);
  };

  handleUpdate = newTime => {
    // get the new date for the showing ...
    this.setState({
      showingTime: newTime,
    });

    // call a function to update the new showing in the DB
    updateShowingInDB(newTime);
    sendEmail(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Modify the showing time</p>
        <DatePickerComponent />
        <button onClick={this.handleUpdate}>Update Showing</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So I see some shared functionality that I'd love to not have to repeat in each component. I'm still learning (working my first job), and why not use this as an opportunity to grow my skills? So I want to get better at the HOC/Render props pattern, but I'm not sure if this is the place to use one.

Should I create a component with a render prop (I'd rather use this pattern instead of a HOC)? I'm not even sure what that would look like, I've read the blogs and watched the talks, ala

```
<MouseMove render={(x, y) => <SomeComponent x={x} y={y} />} />
```

But would this pattern be applicable to my case, or would I be better off defining some lib function that handles formatting that payload for the email and then importing that function into the various components that need it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a provider or a component using render props with branching is a better fit for you here

see this doc: https://lucasmreis.github.io/blog/simple-react-patterns/#render-props